# Usage of sed to add a prefix for a string in linux

Tags: linux, unix

In my problem statement I would like to replace a word with a prefix

```
sed 's/hello-world/'"$1"'-hello-world/g' test.sql
```

Here `$1` is any prefix passed as parameter to the shell script

In this case in the first go it works absolutely fine.
Let's assume "prefix=new"

- It replaces as `new-hello-world` which is a perfect output.
- If i re-run the command again I get `new-new-hello-world` which is not intended
- Run it again i would get `new-new-new-hello-world` which is not intended

How can we search and replace it as `new-hello-world` no matter how many times it is run? Using a regex is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

To make it idempotent, just check first that it doesn't already match.  eg:

```
sed "/$1-hello-world/!s/hello-world/$1-hello-world/g" test.sql
```

This is not particularly robust, and will fail if the original documents contains the line `new-hello-world hello-world`, but is probably sufficient for your needs. (You need to worry more about `/` characters in the prefix, so if you want a robust solution there's a fair bit of work to be done.)

Comment: Thanks William will try and keep you informed